# python video editor library receive file object instead of file path

Tags: django, python-3.x

i am working in django project and i want to make thumbnail from video file saved into defult_storage and i need python video editor library to receive file object instead of file path i check moviepy and  opencv but couldn't fine solution i will be so thankful if someone can help me about this case
this is model:

```
class BusinessVideo(ModificationLogMixin, models.Model):
video = models.FileField(upload_to='business_videos', null=True, blank=True)
```

and this is way i want to pass video to editor

```
video_cap = cv.VideoCapture(default_storage.open(
os.path.relpath(self.video_url, settings.MEDIA_URL)))
```

i need some library to recive file object because my default_storage is based on minio and i don't know how to get video path